# SQL Trigger (as) is not a valid input at this position error - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I am not sure why I am keep getting

> the error on line number 3. (as) is not a valid input at this
>   position?

```
CREATE TRIGGER PendingPublish 
AFTER INSERT ON TopicPending
    AS
BEGIN
IF NEW.TopicApproved = 'YES' THEN
INSERT INTO Topics (Title,Description,Question1,Qustion2,Question3,Question4,UserID)
VALUES (NEW.Title,NEW.Description,NEW.Question1,NEW.Question2,NEW.Question3,NEW.Question4,NEW.UserID);
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `DELIMITER`:

Try this.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER PendingPublish 
AFTER INSERT ON TopicPending
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.TopicApproved = 'YES' THEN
    INSERT INTO Topics (Title,Description,Question1,Qustion2,Question3,Question4,UserID)
    VALUES (NEW.Title,NEW.Description,NEW.Question1,NEW.Question2,NEW.Question3,NEW.Question4,NEW.UserID);
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This doesn't syntax there should be a FOR EACH ROW clause before the begin https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html